# Paypal Adaptive Payments and IOS - prepopulating customer address

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to pre-populate the address of my clients in our mobile app.
So when they're making a purchase using our app they only need to enter their: name, credit card no., security code and expiration date.

We are using Adaptive Payments - Are there any options for (Where can I find documentation)  pre-populating user addresses before the user is redirected to Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language the app is in, but like in PHP you could do something like $_SESSION['address'] and then echo it in the field.

I know the app is not in PHP but I hope this helps.